# python-alarm clock suggestions

Tags: python, time

I am new to python programming and I am trying to apply the concepts I learned recently. I am reading other's code and found an example and tweaked it little bit as seen below. The problem is when the current time equals the wake time, the `elif` block never gets triggered. I have tested that in a small `if-else` statement, it works fine but never gets triggered inside the `while loop`.

Please advise.

```
import time

import subprocess

wake_hour = int(raw_input("Wake hour: "))

wake_minute = int(raw_input("Wake minute: "))

wake_time = [wake_hour, wake_minute]

current_hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))

current_minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))

current_time = [current_hour, current_minute]

while True:

     if current_time != wake_time:
        current_hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
        current_minute = int(time.strftime("%M"))
        print current_hour, current_minute
        print wake_hour, wake_minute

     elif current_time == wake_time:
        audio_file = "/Users/dcasteli/Documents/emergency018.mp3"
        play = subprocess.call(["afplay", audio_file])
        print "Wake up!"
```

Comment: What sample inputs did you use? The program will only work if the user provides input that will be able to match `current_time`.

Comment: When you implement an alarm clock please [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep) until it needs to go off. No need to watch the clock all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only updating the `current_hour` and `current_minute` but in the `elif` statement you are comparing `current_time == wake_time`. The `current_time` value is never updated and will forever remain whatever the user input. In the first `if` statement you should update the `current_time` so the conditional makes sense.